# mongoexport exclude documents

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I have a MongoDB collection with the following documents.  Some of the documents have 1 field and some have 2.  I am interested in exporting only those with 2 fields to a CSV file.  What query can I use to exclude those with 1 field?

```
[
{
    "id" : 1,
},

{
    "id" : 2,
},

{
   "id" : 3
   "productId": 300
}
]
```

my mongoexport command is:  `mongoexport --username x --password x --host x --db mydb --collection mycol --type=csv --fields id,productid --out "c:\myfile.csv"`

Comment: See [`--query`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query) and [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one where i have added query

```
mongoexport --username x --password x --host x --db mydb --collection mycol --type=csv --fields id,productid --query '{ "$and": [ { "id": {"$exists":true}},{"productId":{"$exists":true}}] }' --out "c:\myfile.csv"
```

Or it could be such as

```
mongoexport --username x --password x --host x --db mydb --collection mycol --type=csv --fields id,productid --query '{ "id": {"$exists":true},"productId":{"$exists":true} }' --out "c:\myfile.csv"
```

Comment: Suresh, I tried both methods and I am getting the error "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface{}"

Comment: Use double quotes in query fields like { "id": {"$exists":true},"productId":{"$exists":true} }

Comment: Suresh, your suggestion to use double quotes did actually work.